# scan subnets for ilo ips

Tags: powershell, networking, dns

so i have this script:

```
$srvILO = '172.16.2.210'
$username='svcilo'
$password='xxxx'

$status_message = get-HPiLoFirmwareversion -Server $srvILO -Username $username -Password $password -DisableCertificateAuthentication -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty STATUS_MESSAGE

if ($status_message -eq 'OK'){
Write-Host "Status OK"
Exit 0
}
else {
Write-Host "$status_message"
Exit 0
}
```

I wanne deploy it at several customers that have several subnets and the ilo port is not always on the same ip.

Is there any way that i can scan the subnets to find part of the hostname, which always unclude ILO, and define a variable for the ip adress that is assigned to it?

Something like 
$ILO IP = test-connecten ... scan subnets 192.168.0.210, 192.168.1.210, 192.168.2.210 etc... search for hostname that includes *dns*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to scan all the IP in one range

```
$username='svcilo'
$password='xxxx'
$ipstart = "1"
$ipend = "255"
$ipgroupes = "172.168.2"
$ipstart..$ipend  | ForEach-Object{
$ip = "$ipgroupes.0" -replace "0$",$_ 

$DNSName = Resolve-DnsName -Name $ip | Select NameHost



if ($DNSName -like '*ILO*'){

    $status_message = get-HPiLoFirmwareversion -Server $ip -Username $username -Password $password -DisableCertificateAuthentication -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty STATUS_MESSAGE

    if ($status_message -eq 'OK'){
        Write-Host "Status OK"
        Exit 0
        }

    else {
        Write-Host "$status_message"
        Exit 0
        }

}



}
```

Comment: Any way to use asterix in this command? ``$ComputerName= ‘MetcorpDC01’
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(“$ComputerName”).IPAddressToString``